# Missing FlashVars in Flash Professional CS5 and swfobject?

Tags: flash-cs5

I have a Flash Professional CS5 movie which I'm trying to pass a parameter with swfobject.  The problem is that movieclip's flashvar variables (under loaderInfo.parameters) is null.

Here is the swfobject code:

```
function loadSetupBar(connectId) 
{
  // add the setup bar to the DOM using swfobject
  swfobject.embedSWF("{{setupBarSwf}}",
    "swf-setup-bar",
    {{gameWidth}}, $("#top-bar").height(),
    "10.0.0", "{{installSwf}}",
    {connectionId : connectId },
    {
      allowFullScreen : true,
      wmode : 'opaque',
      allowscriptaccess: "always"
    },
    {name:"swf-setup-bar"}
  );
}
```

According to the swfobject documentation, everything seems to be ok.

Here's the corresponding code inside the FLA (A MovieClip with its own AS3 class):

```
var params : Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
var connectionId : String = params.connectionId;

if ( !params.hasOwnProperty('connectionId') )
   // this line is always printed.
   trace("[SetupBar-Error] loaderInfo parameters missing property 'connectionId'")
```

I'm not sure about what else to do.

Thanks.

EDIT:  Here is a list of things I've tried that have failed:

- casted root.loaderInfo to class LoaderInfo ( i.e. LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo) )
- passing a String literal in swfobject.embedSWF instead of param connectId 
  (i.e. {connectionID : 'myTestValue'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the TLF TEXT control, when you add it to the stage the flashvars begins not working . just don't use it and your flashvars will work fine . i've faced the same problem and i got it solved by not using TLF TEXT control.

I hope i helped .

Best Regards

Comment: if you require tlf text in the project, there is also a workaround on adobe forums. http://forums.adobe.com/message/2832948#2832948

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var params:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
var connectionID:String = params.connectionId;
```

Comment: Can you verify `connectId` is getting passed into `loadSetupBar`?

Comment: Last time I checked that (with Firebug) it was.  However the code has had much change that I'll recheck that ASAP.  EDIT:  See the ammends to the original post.

Comment: In your flash, are you sure you're importing the loaderinfo class?  Like so: `import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;`  - that's all I can think is missing